# Unresolved External Symbol using std::list in a dll

Tags: c++, dll, stl, stdlist

I am trying to learn basics of building a library and DLLs. I have built a simple DLL using MSVC and i can use it in simple console applications via linking.

```
#if defined(DUMMYCLASS_EXPORT)
#define DUMMYCLASS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DUMMYCLASS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <string>
#include <list>

class DUMMYCLASS_API DummyClass
{
public:
    DummyClass(int id, const std::string& name);
    friend std::list<DummyClass>& operator<<(std::list<DummyClass>& dl, const DummyClass& dc);
    void ID(const int newID);
    const int ID();
    void Name(const std::string newName);
    const std::string Name();
private:
    int id;
    std::string name;
};
```

After that i tried to build another DLL which depends on the first DLL i built. Below is the header file of that new class.

```
#pragma once
#if defined(DUMMYWRAPPER_EXPORT)
#define DUMMYWRAPPER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DUMMYWRAPPER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <list>
#include "DummyClass.h"

class DUMMYWRAPPER_API DummyWrapper
{
public:
    DummyWrapper();
    ~DummyWrapper();
    DummyWrapper& operator<<(const DummyClass& dc);
private:
    std::list<DummyClass>* dList;
};
```

I added DummyClass.dll and .lib to my new project but when i try to build it i get an error

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
std::list<class DummyClass,class std::allocator<class DummyClass> > &
__cdecl operator<<(class std::list<class DummyClass,class std::allocator<class DummyClass> > &,class DummyClass const &)"
(??6@YAAAV?$list@VDummyClass@@V?$allocator@VDummyClass@@@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVDummyClass@@@Z)    c:\Users\MCE\documents\visual
studio 2013\Projects\DummyWrapperDLL\DummyWrapperDLL\DummyWrapper.obj   DummyWrapperDLL
```

Right now I don't know what to search for and all my searches end up with somewhat easier and non-relevant linking errors. How do i fix this one?

**EDIT:** 
Here s DummyClass.cpp

```
#define DUMMYCLASS_EXPORT
#include "DummyClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

DummyClass::DummyClass(int newid, const std::string& newname)
    :id(newid), name(newname)
{
    std::cout << "Dummy Object created" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ID: " << id << " / Name: " << name << std::endl;
}

std::list<DummyClass>& operator<<(std::list<DummyClass>& dl, const DummyClass& dc)
{
    dl.push_back(dc);
    return dl;
}

void DummyClass::ID(int newID)
{
    this->id = newID;
    std::cout << "ID changed to " << newID << std::endl;
}

const int DummyClass::ID()
{
    return this->id;
}

void DummyClass::Name(std::string newName)
{
    this->name = newName;
    std::cout << "Name changed to " << newName << std::endl;
}

const std::string DummyClass::Name()
{
    return this->name;
}
```

And this one is DummyWrapper.cpp

```
#define DUMMYWRAPPER_EXPORT
#include "DummyWrapper.h"

DummyWrapper::DummyWrapper()
{
    dList = new std::list<DummyClass>;
}


DummyWrapper::~DummyWrapper()
{
    dList->clear();
    dList = nullptr;
}

DummyWrapper& DummyWrapper::operator<<(const DummyClass& dc)
{
    *dList << dc;
    return *this;
}
```

I also tried giving them different export names but that doesnt work either.

Comment: You *do* implement your `operator<<` function somewhere?

Comment: Did you mark your `operator<<` function with `DUMMYCLASS_API`? See here  for example https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vc.language/sq5_QPuJjgQ

Comment: You mustnt use the same DUMMYCLASS_EXPORT for both dll exports, you need to use another define in the wrapper such that the correct import/export for the dll mix

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes i implement it in DummyWrapper.cpp, i ll edit the question with cpp files too

Comment: @Rostislav: doesn t c++ automatically mark them when i mark the class itself?

Comment: @Niall: i tried that way too, doesnt solve my problem

Comment: I wouldn't think so: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx It says 

"When you declare a class dllexport, all its member functions and static data members are exported".

Friend functions are neither of these. Easiest way to check is just to give it a try.

Comment: Your dummy wrapper header file uses `#if defined(DUMMYCLASS_EXPORT)` and not `#if defined(DUMMYWRAPPERCLASS_EXPORT)`

Comment: @Niall i must have forgotten to update the header file. They actually have the same name, updating question to reflect that and save some more time

Comment: @Rostislav if you can post this as an answer i can accept it. tried it and it compiles now. i thought friend functions would get exported automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `operator <<` of the `DummyClass` before the `DummyClass` and explicitly export it.

The name lookup rules means that the function can be found during compile time, but since the function is not actually a member of the class it is not exported as part of the class, hence the link fails.

Alternatively, don't make it a friend, rather make it a member method.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. it also works like this in the class block, too `DUMMYCLASS_API friend std::list<DummyClass>& operator<<(std::list<DummyClass>& dl, const DummyClass& dc);` it feels more logical to me when the method is inside the class

Comment: Very interesting. Didn't know you could export from within a class.